# Display an image using "Photos metro application"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-mobile

I'm trying to display an image using "Photos metro application" (C++).
Below is teh code snippet using which I'm able to display images. 
But I want to use only "Photos" metro app to display my images. 
If I right click on each image manually & change it's default application as "Photos" in properties menu then the below code snippet is working fine for display images using "Photos application".

But I want to embed this control of choosing which appliation to use for displaying images in mu code. 
**How do I force my code to display an image say "color.png" using Photos metro app?**

```
int DisplayImage(std::string image)
{
    printf("\nThe image is %s", image);
    std::string command = "Start " + image;
    system(command.c_str());
......
......
}
```

> I want to run this code on a mobile phone/tablet but my code generates
>   an EXE (not a metro Windows store app). I use TSHELL to run my EXE in
>   mtero mobile phone/tablet enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

How do you plan to handle the scenario where the user doesn't have the Photos app installed?

You can launch the photo in the default handler (as you are doing) and it will display in the Photos app if that is what the user has chosen. This is generally the right thing to do and is user-friendly. This is the only way to programmatically launch the photo or the Photos app in a Windows Store app.

From a desktop app you can explicitly activate a Windows Runtime app with a file by calling the [IActivateActivationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)::[ActivateForFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706904(v=vs.85).aspx) method. This cannot be called from a Windows Runtime app. Like your existing code, it won't run on a production phone.

To write a Windows Runtime app (either Windows Store or Windows Phone Store) you'll need to start with one of the Windows Store templates in Visual Studio. You cannot write a console app as a Windows Runtime app. See [Get started](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted) in the [Windows Developer Center](http://dev.windows.com) on MSDN for an overview of how to write Windows Runtime apps.